# PDE change of variables in derivation of KP equation from Hirota bilinear equation

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations

I want to derive the KP equation

$$\partial_{x_1}(\partial_{x_3}z-6z(\partial_{x_1}z)-\partial_{x_1}^3z)=3\partial_{x_2}^2z$$

from the Hirota bilinear equation

$$(\partial_{u_1}^4+3\partial_{u_2}^2-4\partial_{u_1}\partial_{u_3})\tau(x+u)\tau(x-u)=0$$

where the derivatives are evaluated at $u=0$ and where $\tau$ is some polynomial.

**Attempt at solution:**

I've gathered from [1] (7.17) that one is to solve this by the substitution $z = 2\partial_{x_1}^2log\tau$. I've evaluated the Hirota bilinear equation to

$$2(\partial_{x_1}^4 \tau)\tau-8(\partial_{x_1}^3\tau)(\partial_{x_1}\tau) + 6(\partial_{x_1}^2\tau)^2+6(\partial_{x_2}^2\tau)\tau-6(\partial_{x_2}^2\tau)^2-8(\partial_{x_1}\partial_{x_3}\tau)\tau+8(\partial_{x_1}\tau)(\partial_{x_3}\tau)=0$$

where $\tau = \tau(x)$. However, I am stuck on simplifying further from here. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

--

[1] Kac, Raina. Bombay Lectures on Highest Weight Representations of Infinite-Dimensional Lie Algebras